# Ember reload unloaded models

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

In my application I load model for route like this:

```
    @modelFor('stream').get('messages')
```

But there are a lot of messages and when I change stream I want to unload messages from previous stream to increase performance:

```
   @modelFor('stream').get('messages').toArray().forEach (r)=>
    @store.unloadRecord(r)
```

The problem is: when I return to already unloaded stream I get no messages. I tried to do `@modelFor('stream').get('messages').reload()`, but I get nothing...

Can anyone tell me how to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When model is unloaded, all relations are unloaded as well.
It means `stream` doesn't know about unloaded `messages`.
Solution is to load messages back using query:

```
beforeModel: ->
  @store.find 'message', stream_id: @modelFor('stream').get('id')
```

Then

```
@modelFor('stream').get('messages')
```

will work as expected.